# How to compare between two rows in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table name Meetings with column Numbers (integer) :

```
 Numbers
    1
    2
    3
    14
    19
```

I need to run on Numbers column and when a gap of one number or more is found, I need to get the first value of that gap - for example 3,14. what is the best way to do that? a simple select or should I use a cursor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select number
from (select t.*,
             lead(number) over (order by number) as next_number
      from t
     ) t
where next_number <> number + 1;
```

Follow [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) for more information.